# Malloc with 3 star ptr

Tags: c, malloc

```
void alloc (int*** matr, int r, int c)
{
int i, j;
*matr=malloc(r*sizeof(***matr));
for (i=0; i<r; i++)
    *matr[i]=malloc(c*sizeof(**matr));

for (i=0; i<r; i++)
    for (j=0; j<c; j++)
        *matr[i][j]=12;
}
```

The function prototype is given by the teacher. The error i receive is segmentation fault. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: What do you want to accomplish. Please specify.

Comment: Being a 3-star programmer is not a compliment in C! That looks awful, if the prototype really was supplied by the teacher, instantly get a new teacher!

Comment: Any idea? @Bathsheba

Comment: I want just to allocate the matrix and to assign a value @AhmedAkhtar

Comment: Not really.  Requires guessing at the parameters and functionality.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Andrew - Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This post needs a clearer title.

Comment: Are you going for a 2D matrix or a 3D one?

Comment: What is wrong with some typedefs?  I don't care about cargo-cult 'no typedefs for pointers', anything is better than three stars.

Comment: @Andrew You did not answer my question about the matrix being 2D or 3D. Anyways, I posted an answer assuming that you want 2D. Please specify if you want otherwise.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar i want a 2D matrix

Comment: @Olaf - sometimes higher levels of indirection are unavoidable; given what this code is obviously meant to do, it's not too egregious.  I would rather it return the pointer than write it to a parameter, but hey...

Comment: @MartinJames: A `typedef` does not change the underlying semantics. Likely still awfull.

Comment: @JohnBode: A 3-level indirect is very rarely of use. And here it is useless, as you already wrote. Why use another indirection just to "return" a pointer, but have the function `void`? That is just bad style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `matr` is initialized, the statement

```
*matr=malloc(r*sizeof(***matr)); // ***matr is of "int" type
```

should be

```
*matr = malloc(r*sizeof(int *));   // Allocate an array of "r" int *
//matr[0] = malloc(r*sizeof(int *));
```

and in `for` loop, the statement

```
*matr[i]=malloc(c*sizeof(**matr));  // **mtr is of "int *" type
```

should be

```
(*matr)[i] = malloc(c*sizeof(int)); // Allocate an array of "c" int
//matr[0][i] = malloc(c*sizeof(int));
```

and then chage `*matr[i][j]=12;` to `(*matr)[i][j]=12;` or `matr[0][i][j]=12;`

See an example of working code: https://ideone.com/hboLKV

Comment: and there's a missing sizeof(int) in that galaxy of stars somewhere.

Comment: Both lines are the same.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar Examine closer..

Comment: @Bathsheba; `sizeof(**matr)` is ultimately `sizeof(int *)`.

Comment: Only if you're star-blinded.

Comment: Yes, code is more robust when you refer to the size of the variable, not its presumed type.

Comment: this implementation doesn't work. In the second for, it allocates just one coloumn, as if the variable c was 1, but it is 3

Comment: @MartinJames; Was [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322833/malloc-with-3-star-ptr/35322890#comment58354583_35322890) for me?

Comment: I tried this version too, but nothing to do @haccks

Comment: @Andrew; This will work 100%. I added link of working code.

Comment: @haccks I was hoping someone would show how OP's function should be called, but although you sidestepped that +1.

Comment: @haccks nah - Ahmed.  TBH, anyone looking at a question like this is likely to suffer from star-blindness:(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code, if you want to implement a 2D Matrix using a triple pointer:

```
void alloc (int*** matr, int r, int c)
{
 int i, j;
 *matr = malloc(r*sizeof(int*));
 for (i=0; i<r; i++)
  (*matr)[i] = malloc(c*sizeof(int));

 for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
   (*matr)[i][j] = 12;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I receive also this warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] , refered to line 7 @AhmedAkhtar

Comment: @Andrew Yeah right. Now I ran your code. I am editing the correct version.